# EOL error while converting string / to \

Tags: python

```
def replc(path):
    path.replace('/','\')
    return path
```

This definition gives me EOL error, how exactly can i replace it?

Comment: did you see the color color of `return` stmt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
path.replace('/','\\')
```

the backslash is used to escape special characters in python so to use an actual backslash you have to escape it. [python string-literals](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

Comment: yes that works fine, although it should be path.replace('//','\')